# Filling the form fields with log result in Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

So right now I have a grabResult.js page that I use to grab a result:

```
module.exports = async function grabResult(page) {
  const name = await page.$eval(
    'divtograbname',
    (el) => el.innerText
  );

  const price = await page.$eval(
    'divtograbprice',
    (el) => el.innerText
  );

  return { name, price };
};
```

Using the below code on my main app.js page I can output the log result successfully:

```
  while (true) {
    const result = await grabResult(page);
    console.log(result);
```

The above is outputting both: name and price

The next step is I'm trying to put name and price into the fields on my website.

I know how to fill the form field with my desired value:

```
await page.$eval('input[name=wc_name]', 'mydesiredvalue');
```

Basically, I'm trying to fill my form fields with my grabbed name and price values.

I have tried:

```
await page.$eval('input[name=wc_name]', 'name');
await page.$eval('input[name=wc_price]', 'price');
```

The above just fill the fields with text: 'name' and 'price'. It can't identify the return values from my grabResult page.

I have also tried

```
await page.$eval('input[name=wc_name]', $name);
await page.$eval('input[name=wc_price]', $price);
```

I have even tried this to see if it fill both into one:

```
await page.$eval('input[name=wc_name]', console.log(result));
```

Can't make it work.

I know I'm missing something here. I'm not a coder. Just trying to combine few blocks into one.

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting back something called an object, it looks like this:

```json
{
    name: 'name_value',
    price: 1
}
```

`name` and `price` are properties. In order to get the property `price`, you can type `my_object_name.price`, so in your example `result.price`.

Then in Puppeteer, you usually fill values with [`page.type()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pagetypeselector-text-options) method:

```js
await page.type('input[name=wc_name]', result.name);
await page.type('input[name=wc_price]', result.price);
```

This should work fine.

Comment: hey pavelsaman, it didn't worked. Using console.log(result.name)); did successfully outputted name value in the terminal. But using your line, it put blank into the field input. I noticed I can put data manually with await page.$eval('input[name=wc_name]', el => el.value = 'usernamegoeshere'); But using your await page.type('input[name=wc_name]', 'usernamegoeshere'); did not put any data manually into the field. Just trying to figured out what's wrong.

Comment: I have also tried await page.$eval('input[name=wc_name]', el => el.value = result.name); but that didn't put nothing into the field.

Comment: `page.type()` sends keydown, keypress, keyup events for each character. It works differently than `page.$eval()`. It depends on how the app works, it's hard to say like this without actually seeing the application. If `page.$eval()` works in your situation, you can keep it that way of course.

Comment: Are you sure you have the right selector?

Comment: Sorry, not really sure what you mean. Basically my logic is this. If right now I can put data manually into my website input field using await page.$eval('input[name=wc_name]', el => el.value = 'my-manually-written-name-goes-here'); then somehow by knowing how to correctly enter the result.name, I should be able to put the result.name into the field input. As I mentioned, I have tried  await page.$eval('input[name=wc_name]', el => el.value = result.name); but that didn't worked. I know I could be making mistakes somewhere in the code line.